# Remove table from email vba

Tags: vba, outlook

i receive from some colleagues email that contain tables and i have asked them not to put tables. Is there a way that when i replay to them to remove the tables but not the information from the table? Thank you.

I have tried

Dim aTable As Table

For Each aTable In objItem.Tables
 aTable.Delete
Next

Comment: A phone call should suffice... Seriously though, what have you tried?

Comment: yes, but they don't care.

Comment: Can you share an image of the email, an example of how it looks

Comment: In an Html body a table is "<table ... </table>" where table can be upper or lower case.  You may need to allow for nested tables: "<table ... <table ... </table>  ... </table>"  They should not be difficult to locate and remove.

Comment: Hi, so i need to remove from the body the tabs <table  </table> ? The table has no standard - it can be 2*3 or 7*10 . I found how to remove tables from word,access, excel but not from outlook email.

Comment: A mail item has a text body and an Html body. Rtf is a user option but it is only available to VBA as Html. If there is an html body you are not shown the text body which in my experience is usually rubbish anyway. I can find nothing that suggests that Outlook VBA has routines for accessing tables within an Html body. This seems reasonable since Excel and Access have structures to which a table could be moved but Outlook doesn't. An Outlook Html body is a string. Outlook uses a browser of your choice to display Html bodies so that string can contain anything that your browser can handle. ...

Comment: ... The number of rows and columns does not matter. Cells are always nested within rows and rows are nested within tables. If the Html body has been designed to displayable on a variety of media (PCs, smartphones, etc.) there may be nested tables.  That is, a cell may contain a complete table and a cell within that table might contain another table. The most complex I have seen involved six levels of nesting. Think of "<table" as an opening bracket and "</table" as the closing bracket. You must delete from each opening bracket to its matching closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

The routine below has been tested but not to my entire satisfaction.  I have run out of time today and it will be Monday evening before I will be free to look at this again.

I probably would not have answered this question but I have never amended an email’s body before and I this was a good excuse to try.  I found it worrying easy.  People trust emails but what is to stop me amending an email from someone to say they agree to pay £500 (mustn’t be too greedy, it would look suspicious) for programming services?

This code relies on Outlook Explorer.  The user selects some emails and then calls the macro to process the selected emails.  The macro does not amend the original email.  It creates a copy with the subject suffixed with “ with tables removed” and amends that.

The macro does what you ask but I am concerned it is not what you need.  If these emails contain the text you want plus tables that you don’t, this will remove the tables.  If these emails are being created for several people and you are the only one who does not want the tables then I can understand why the senders cannot be bothered to create a table-less version for you. However, if these emails are designed to be read on different media types, the text you want may be within a table. If these emails are being created using some multi-media package, there may be nothing the senders can do.

I have left my diagnostic code within the macro.  Try it out and tell me how it works for you.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DeleteTables()

  ' Deletes any tables within selected mail items.

  '  7Jan17  Coded.  Based on Demo Explorer

  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim HtmlBodyLc As String
  Dim PosTabEnd As Long
  Dim PosTabOuter As Long
  Dim PosTabStart As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim ItemNew As MailItem
  Dim NumNested As Long
  Dim NumNestedMax As Long

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("No emails selected", vbOKOnly)
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Set ItemNew = ItemCrnt.Copy           ' Create copy so original not changed
      With ItemNew
        Debug.Print .Sender & " " & .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject
        .Subject = .Subject & " with tables removed"
        HtmlBodyLc = LCase(.HtmlBody)       ' Lower case version of Html body for searching
        NumNested = 0    ' Not within table
        PosTabStart = InStr(1, HtmlBodyLc, "<table")
        PosTabEnd = InStr(1, HtmlBodyLc, "</table>")
        Do While True
          If PosTabStart = 0 Then
            ' No more start tags
            Do While NumNested > 1
              ' Search for end tags to match open start tags
              PosTabEnd = InStr(PosTabEnd + 8, HtmlBodyLc, "</table>")
              NumNested = NumNested - 1
              Debug.Print NumNested & Space(1 + NumNested * 5) & PadL(PosTabEnd, 5)
            Loop
            If PosTabEnd > 0 And NumNested = 1 Then
              ' Have end tag that matches outer start tag.
              ' Everything between these two tags is part of a table
              PosTabEnd = PosTabEnd + 8    ' Position after end tag
              .HtmlBody = Mid(.HtmlBody, 1, PosTabOuter - 1) & _
                          Mid(.HtmlBody, PosTabEnd)
              Debug.Print "Delete " & PosTabOuter & " to " & PosTabEnd - 1
              Exit Do  ' All tables removed from this mail item
            Else
              ' Some mismatch between start and end tags.
              Debug.Assert False
            End If
          End If
          ' At least one more table
          If PosTabStart < PosTabEnd Then
            ' Start of next table before end of any outer table.
            If NumNested = 0 Then
              ' This is an outer table
              PosTabOuter = PosTabStart
            End If
            NumNested = NumNested + 1
            Debug.Print NumNested & Space(1 + NumNested * 5) & PadL(PosTabStart, 5)
            PosTabStart = InStr(PosTabStart + 6, HtmlBodyLc, "<table") ' Find next if any
          Else
            ' End of previous table before start of new table.
            PosTabEnd = PosTabEnd + 8    ' Position after end tag
            If NumNestedMax < NumNested Then
              NumNestedMax = NumNested
            End If
            Debug.Print NumNested & Space(1 + NumNested * 5) & PadL(PosTabEnd, 5)
            NumNested = NumNested - 1
            If NumNested = 0 Then
              ' Have found end tag for outer table.  Delete it and any nested
              ' tables from both body and copy so they continue to match.
                .HtmlBody = Mid(.HtmlBody, 1, PosTabOuter - 1) & _
                            Mid(.HtmlBody, PosTabEnd)
                HtmlBodyLc = Mid(HtmlBodyLc, 1, PosTabOuter - 1) & _
                            Mid(HtmlBodyLc, PosTabEnd)
                Debug.Print "Delete " & PosTabOuter & " to " & PosTabEnd - 1
                ' Need new values for PosTabStart and PosTabEnd becauseof deletion
                PosTabStart = InStr(PosTabOuter, HtmlBodyLc, "<table")
                If PosTabStart = 0 Then
                  ' Last table processed
                  Exit Do
                End If
                PosTabEnd = InStr(PosTabOuter, HtmlBodyLc, "</table>")
            ElseIf NumNested > 0 Then
              ' Need to find more end tags before end tag for outer start tag found
              PosTabEnd = InStr(PosTabEnd, HtmlBodyLc, "</table>")  ' Find next if any
            Else   ' NumNested < 0
              ' More end tags than start tags. Can do nothing about faulty Html
              Debug.Assert False
              Exit Do
            End If
          End If
        Loop
        Debug.Assert InStr(1, LCase(.Body), "<table") = 0
        Debug.Assert InStr(1, LCase(.Body), "</table") = 0
        'debug.print .subject
        .Save
      End With
    Next
  End If
End Sub
Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
              Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```